# Is there a way to exploit 4-byte integer overflows to -1? [memcpy(dest, source, -1)]

Tags: exploit

I was debugging a program, and discovered a line of code like so:

```
memcpy(stack_variable, attacker_supplied, read_length_from_packet(pPacket));
```

The `read_length_from_packet` returns -1 if the length is bigger than 0x1FF, but seems they forgot to actually check for -1.

And since `memcpy` takes a `size_t` (unsigned), the -1 gets converted to 0xFFFFFFFF, and I can *massively* override the stack, so much it writes on memory it shouldn't, raises an exception, and crashes.

Is there a way to make an exploit out of this, or it'll just stay in a crash?

Comment: Unix or Windows? In Windows, maybe, see the answer of @0x41414141. In Unix, no, there is nothing like SEH handlers, it will stay as a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a simple buffer overflow, so probably yes, depending on what mitigations are available on the software/system you are targeting.

What you need to do is to overwrite something useful like:

- return address stored on the stack.
- SE handler address stored on the stack.
- anything that lets you control the execution flow of the program.

Comment: so if I put my handler's address in the payload, memcpy copies it, and then raises an exception, I can catch it?